# Simple question: Cisco 1750 AUX Port as "ADSL WIC"

Tags: cisco, isp, pppoe, adsl

I'm going to buy a Cisco 1750, but its lack the ADSL WIC Module. My question is, **can I use the AUX Port to plug my RJ11 for  DSL PPPoE Authentication?** Like this:

```
          Cisco 1750
ISP --- AUX ------ F0/0 --- INTERNAL
```

If not, will I be able to do this with a consumer dlink modem?

```
ISP --- D-LINK MODEM ---- f0/0 CISCO 1750 f0/1 ---- INTERNAL
          BRIDGED              (PPPoE Auth)
```

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first diagram will not work, and in fact may result in damage to your router. The AUX port is a regular RS232 serial port, which is completely incompatible with ADSL. **Don't do it.**

The second diagram should work, provided your D-Link modem can operate in bridged mode.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The modem does support bridge, so it's ok. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Except the 1750 only has **one** fastethernet port. A WIC-1ENET is 10m, WIC-4ESW a 4 port switch... but they both live on the WIC bus that'll top out about 6-8m.  Depending on your DSL speed, this may not be a problem.  I use a WIC-1ADSL (and WIC-4ESW) in a 1720, but the DSL line is 6m anyway.

(and neither the 1720 nor 1750 support dot1q; that's a feature of the 17x1 line.)

Comment: Also consider the effects of Csma/CD if you negotiate at  10/half.  This ultimately punishes you for bidirectional traffic

Comment: 10base-whatever doesn't do autoneg. If you want full-duplex, *you* have to set both ends to full. (which is why my cable modem had to go through a switch first.)

Comment: Assuming the opposite side supports autoneg, it will see the lack of c1700 autoneg pulses and fall back to 10/half.  I agree that negotiate is the wrong term here.